# Access a named TextBox in the code behind from a ContentPresenter's DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, datatemplate

I am trying to get access to a named `TextBox` (textBoxAnswer) in the code behind of my WPF Page. The trouble is, because it is part of a `DataTemplate`, it is not auto-generated as a private member of the class, like it would be if I wasn't using the `ContentPresenter` + `DataTemplate`. (I am using the `DataTemplate` because I need to use `DataTrigger`s, not included in the example below).

I have tried calling `FindResource("textBoxAnswer")` and `FindName("textBoxAnswer")`, but neither return anything.

Any suggestions? Here is a stripped down version of my XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="LearningGames.Numbers.NumbersPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="textBoxAnswer"
                Text="{Binding Answer}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a name to the `ContentPresenter` (I will assume it is `cpAnswer`), and access the textbox with the `FindName` method of the template :

```
TextBox textBoxAnswer = cpAnswer.ContentTemplate.FindName("textBoxAnswer", cpAnswer) 
as TextBox;
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks! I have accepted the answer, but you had a small mistake which I have fixed - should be .ContentTemplate, not .DataTemplate. Also, should not be called in the constructor, but only after the page has loaded.