# Access DataTemplate Control At Run Time

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am Working on Windows phone 8.1.I Making Simple ListView Demo Which is Contain two Image And Two TextBlock.

```
     <ListView x:Name="lst1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image x:Name="imgSender" Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,15,8,8" />
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Sender}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>

                    <Image x:Name="imgReceiver" Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Grid.Row="1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Receiver}"  FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Image Source="Assets/scroll_line_addcategory.png" Grid.Row="2" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="4,8,4,0" />
                </Grid>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And My Problem is That I Want to Set the Visibility of 'imgSender' at Runtime in Xaml.cs File.
Is Anybuddy Have Any Idea For Access UI Control Contain by Data Template.

Comment: Create a `bool` field in your collection , then bind the visibility to it using a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758656/Use-Converters-in-your-Windows-Phone-Apps) `Visibility="{Binding ShowImgReceiver, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"`

Comment: Hello Barnstokkt, I am Beginner so It's might be possible i am Wrong.  Is this Possible To do This Without using Any Class..???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Without using Any Class" everything in C# is a class (except technically void)

Comment: Simple Model Class. i am Using MVVM Architecture.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ListView x:Name="lst1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image  Visibility="{Binding SenderVisibility}" x:Name="imgSender" Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,15,8,8" />
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Sender}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>

                    <Image x:Name="imgReceiver" Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Grid.Row="1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Receiver}"  FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Image Source="Assets/scroll_line_addcategory.png" Grid.Row="2" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="4,8,4,0" />
                </Grid>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And my Model Class is
 public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string sender = string.Empty;
        private string receiver = string.Empty;
        private string senderVisibility = string.Empty;
        private string receiverVisibility = string.Empty;
        public string Sender
        {
            get
            {
                return sender;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.sender)
                {
                    this.sender = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Sender");
                }
            }
        }

```
    public string Receiver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.receiver;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.receiver)
            {
                this.receiver = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Receiver");
            }
        }
    }
    public string ReceiverVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.receiverVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.receiverVisibility)
            {
                this.receiverVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ReceiverVisibility");
            }
        }
    }
    public string SenderVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.senderVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.senderVisibility)
            {
                this.senderVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SenderVisibility");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: It's Not Working justin.

Comment: do you have a viewmodel for XAMl class?

Comment: Ya I have Model Class.If i am use Model Class Than It's Properly Work.but my Question i That If I Don't Want To use Model Class And Access the Property of ImgSender in Xaml.cs Class.Is this Possible..???

Comment: In Xaml.cs access the Model class by (this.DataContext as ClassViewModel).GridViewModel

Comment: Do you have any Referance Demo or Link..??

Comment: If you are that particular you can use ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(yourListBoxItem);DataTemplate yourDataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;Image img = yourDataTemplate.FindName("imgSender", contentPresenter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379946/how-to-access-a-control-within-data-template-from-code-behind

Comment: I m Sorry Guys it's not properly implemented in My Code May Be it's My Mistake.I Will try at my Best.If I got Solution than I am Telling you. And Thank You Very Much Justin

Answer (score 0):

If your `ListView` contains only one item you can easily subscribe to `Loaded` event of `imgSender` and then control it's `Visibility`.

```
private Image _imgSender;

void Image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     _imgSender = sender as Image();
}

void AnotherMethod()
{
      if (_imgSender != null)
         _imgSender.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**EDIT**
**FOR MULTIPLE ITEMS**

```
void HideImage(int elementIndex)
{
    var container = lst1.ContainerFromIndex(elementIndex) as ListViewItem;

   var imageSender = (container.Content as Grid).Children[0] as Image;
   imageSender.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Ya i know this but I Required Multiple Item.

Comment: in This Code It's Give me Null Referance Error in Following line. var imageSender = (container.Content as Grid).Children[0] as Image;

Comment: What is Element Index in This Code..?? I am Pass Following As Static in Page Load Event.  var container = lst1.ContainerFromItem(lst1.Items[0]) as ListViewItem;

Comment: elementIndex - index of ListView item you want to modify.

Comment: Check Edit in You Code.this Above Edited Code give me null Reference Error.

Comment: @ChiragSolanki, you may need to chenge 'imageSender' as your DataTemplate may vary.

Comment: @ChiragSolanki you got NullReferenseException because you run this code in Loaded event of page when ListView HAS NO ITEMS!

Comment: Here "ls" is   public static ObservableCollection<User> ls = new ObservableCollection<User>();

Comment: @ChiragSolanki just use the code after you can be 100% sure that ListView had render all it's items properly.

Comment: @ChiragSolanki, and if it still will get you null exception check if container is null or not. if it's not, check all it's content until you will find your image in children-parent tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758656/Use-Converters-in-your-Windows-Phone-Apps)

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="lst1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding TelecomCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
            <Grid>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="imgSender" Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,15,8,8" 
                      Visibility="{Binding ShowImgReceiver, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Sender}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>

                <Image x:Name="imgReceiver" Source="Assets/button_register.png"  Grid.Row="1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Receiver}"  FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/scroll_line_addcategory.png" Grid.Row="2" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="4,8,4,0" />
            </Grid>


        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in your item class you can add `ShowImgReceiver`

```
public class Telecom
{
     string Receiver {get; set;}
     string Sender {get; set;}
     bool ShowImgReceiver{get; set;}
}
```

In your binding class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Telecom> TelecomCollection {get; set;}
}
```

If you want to make an item's image visibility `Collapsed`, then

```
 TelecomCollection[0].ShowImgReceiver = false;
```

and to make it again `Visible`

```
 TelecomCollection[0].ShowImgReceiver = true;
```